# Dockerize FIWARE can't notify a service

Tags: docker, postman, fiware, fiware-orion

I just started to use FIWARE. I downloaded the latest version [on the website](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html) (v2) using docker-compose on a PopOs distro.
I'm using Postman to make requests (create the entities and subscriptions) and a Laravel application to listen the notification from the FIWARE subscriptions. But for some reason, today, when I started the docker service and start to send requests: the FIWARE notifications suddenly stopped to work.

When I access the subscriptions endpoint FIWARE returns:

```
        "notification": {
            "timesSent": 1,
            "lastNotification": "2021-09-02T01:19:39.000Z",
            "attrs": [],
            "onlyChangedAttrs": false,
            "attrsFormat": "keyValues",
            "http": {
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/notifications"
            },
            "lastFailure": "2021-09-02T01:19:39.000Z",
            "lastFailureReason": "Couldn't connect to server"
        }
```

FIWARE can't comunicate, but if I make a POST request using Postman for that endpoint (`http://localhost:8000/api/notifications`) it returns 200.

There's some aditional configuration between the FIWARE docker container and the local machine? Or I'm doing something wrong?

This is my entity:

```
// http://{{orion}}/v2/subscription

{
    "id": "movie",
    "type": "movie",
    "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "value": "movie name"
    },
    "gender": {
        "type": "text",
        "value": "drama"
    }
}
```

This is how I'm doing the subscription:

```
// http://{{orion}}/v2/subscriptions

{
    "description": "Notify me about any movie of gender drama",
    "subject": {
        "entities": [{"idPattern": ".*","type": "movie"}],
        "condition": {
            "attrs": ["gender"],
            "expression": {
                "q": "gender==drama"
            }
        }
    },
    "notification": {
        "http": {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/notifications"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Docker, then you need to consider what `http://localhost:8000/api/notifications` actually means. `localhost` will mean the `localhost` as experienced by the Orion container itself. Generally Orion listens on 1026 and there is nothing listening on 8000 within a dockerized Orion, therefore your subscription fails.

If you have another micro-service running within the same docker network and in a separate container you must use the `hostname` of that container (or an `alias` or defined IP) to describe the notification URL, not `localhost`.

So for example in the following [tutorial](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subscriptions.html) where a subscription payload is displayed on screen:

```sh
curl -iX POST \
  --url 'http://localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "description": "Notify me of all product price changes",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [{"idPattern": ".*", "type": "Product"}],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [ "price" ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://tutorial:3000/subscription/price-change"
    }
  }
}'
```

refers to a container which is called `tutorial` within the docker network

```yaml
  tutorial:
    image: fiware/tutorials.context-provider
    hostname: tutorial
    container_name: fiware-tutorial
    depends_on:
      - orion
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - iot-sensors
          - context-provider
    expose:
      - 3000
```

As it happens the tutorial container is also exposing its internal port 3000 to the localhost of the machine it is running on so it can be viewed by a user, but Orion can only access it via the hostname on the docker network.